# c program for word ladder

Tags: c, cpu-word

I have written C code for word ladder.
It is validating for given test cases. but for 1 test case it's output is wrong I'm not getting where should I make changes.

Question

> There is a class of word puzzles where you are given two words, such as BEAK and MAKE, and have to get from one to another by changing one letter at a time. Solving such puzzles requires a good vocabulary and some lateral thinking, but checking the solution once you have one is merely tedious and suitable for a computer to do. Note that even correct solutions are not guaranteed to be minimal.
>
> A solution is correct if, for each pair of adjacent words in the ladder, the following apply:
>
> - they are the same length
> - there is exactly one letter changed.
>
> Write a program that will check proposed solutions.
>
> **Input Format:**
>
> Input will be a solution i.e it consists of a series of words, one per line, terminated
>   by a line containing a single #. A word is a sequence --- between three and twenty uppercase letters.
>
> **Output Format:**
>
> Output the word ‘Correct’ or ‘Incorrect’ as appropriate.
>
> Sample Input 1:

```
BARK
BARE
#
```

> Sample Output 1:

```
Correct
```

> Sample Input 2:

```
MAKE
BAKE
BONK
BONE
BANE
#
```

> Sample Output 2:

```
Incorrect
```

My code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  int i,count;
  char a[100],b[100],c[100];
  int flag=1;
  scanf("%s",a);
  do
  {
 scanf("%s",b);
    if(b[0]=='#')
   break;
    if(strlen(a)==strlen(b))
    {  i=0,count=0;
     while(a[i]!='\0')
     {

       if(a[i]!=b[i])
         count++;
         if(count==2)
         {
         flag=0;
         }

       i++;
     }
   }
    else
    {
      flag=0;
    }
    scanf("%s",a);
    if(a[0]=='#')
      break;
   //  scanf("%s",c);
   strcpy(c,a);
   strcpy(a,b);
    strcpy(b,c);

   }
   while(a[0]!='#');
  if(flag==1)
   printf("Correct");
  else
    printf("Incorrect");
   return 0;
   }
```

programs output is incorrect for this input

> code -> cade -> cate -> date -> data

Comment: So, when is your deadline?

Comment: @gustafbstrom today is deadline..

Comment: In C you can do arithmetic with chars. Example 'a' - 'b' yields -1 (!=0). Maybe you can improve your solution with that idea.

Comment: And please format your code. It hurts.

Comment: @ Elyasin whats is wrong in my logic??

Comment: The reading and swapping of lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading words too many times.  I mean, you read more than you compare.

Check this out:

1. first `scanf()` (into `a`) doesn't count. It's used to have something to compare
2. second `scanf()` (into `b`) in the loop
3. comparison of `a` and `b` in the loop
4. third `scanf()` (into `a`) in the loop!!
5. repeat at 2.

You should only have 1 `scanf()` and 1 comparison inside the loop.

<sub>*Also your indentation hurts.*</sub>

Comment: 1. read `a`; 2 read `b`; 3 compare `a` and `b`; 4 copy `b` to `a`; 5 goto 2